# Java sever code to Push Notification to particular device in Android

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app where in I will require the push notifications.
I have done client side application but i want server side application using java.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Then you would want to take a look at **Google Cloud Messaging for Android Libary**. Install it from the SDK Manager, and you'll get Client & Server example source code.

Refer to the following links:

GCM: Getting Started:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

Tutorial:
http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/